# selenium IDE verify if this div or that item is showing

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

So I am using selenium IDE and creating a test on a search page. The page will either show a jqgrid that diplays the results, or show a div with a message that says no records found.

both of these items have a css display of Disabled or Display: none. If results, the grid is set to show, or if there are no results the div message is set to show and the grid stays as display: none.

Thought maybe I could use javascipt in a store to grab the display status of both items and set a var if either one shows up, and then assert if the var is True, else the test will fail.

I just can't seem to figure out if this can be done and if it can, how?

I know I can use javascript to create a dynamic date, but can i do more with javascript in my situation?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use "gotoIf" function, enabled from "goto_sel_ide.js" extension:

Try using following code or rework it for your needs :)

```
type css=search field aaa (example)
click css=search_button (example)
storeElementPresent elementWithJQgrid jqvariable
storeElementPresent elementWithDiv divvariable
label CheckAgain
gotoIf ${jqvariable}==true jqlabelYes
gotoIf ${jqvariable}==false jqlabelNo
label jqlabelYes
//instructions if JQgrid is visible
goto NextThingToDo
label jqlabelNo
gotoIf ${divvariable}==true divlabelYes
gotoIf ${divvariable}==false divlabelNo
label divlabelYes
//instructions if Div is visible
goto NexThingToDo
label divlabelNo
//if both aren't visible, checkagain
goto CheckAgain
label NextThingToDo
//next instruction if JQgrid or Div is visible
```

As you can see, operating with "gotoIf" might be useful or painful, because it's harder to read the code. I hope it helps!

Comment: This was exactly what I needed....i was able to take your code above and make it work exactly for me. Thanks for the help.